# Second SQL statement is not inserting/updating, but first is

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to execute two sql statements in a row.  EDIT:Only the first textbox "boxes" posts correctly. It seems that the 3 other variables, bubbleWrap, studentAddress1, and studentAddress2 are all blank.  Both SQL statements work in the mysql workbench.

The textboxes for studentAddress1 and studentAddress 2 are included in the same form as boxes and the bubblewrap (true/false) radio buttons. I can include the form if you would like, but it is pretty straightforward and basic.

AJAX:

```
$("#needEmptyBoxesForm").submit (function() {
    alert('click');
    boxes = $("#boxes").val();
    bubbleWrap = $("#bubbleWrap").val();
    studentAddress1 = $("#studentAddress1").val();
    studentAddress2 = $("#studentAddress2").val();

    $.post('needEmptyBoxesRequest.php', 'boxes=' + boxes + 'bubbleWrap=' + bubbleWrap + 'studentAddress1=' + studentAddress1 + 'studentAddress2=' + studentAddress2, function (response) {
    alert('post');
    $("#needEmptyBoxesRequestResults").html(response);
    alert (response);
    });
return false;
});
```

Processing page (php)

```
    else {
    $boxes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['boxes']);
    $bubbleWrap = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bubbleWrap']);
    $studentAddress1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentAddress1']);
    $studentAddress2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentAddress2']);

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["email"]);
    $clientId = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["clientId"]);

    $sql =  "INSERT INTO supplies (`clientId`, `boxesRequested`, `bubbleWrapRequested`)
                VALUES ('".$clientId."', '".$boxes."', '".$bubbleWrap."');";

    //set results to variables
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        //in case query fails
        if (!$result) { 
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
        }

    $sql2 =     "UPDATE `clients` SET `studentAddress1`= '".$studentAddress1."',`studentAddress2`= '".$studentAddress2."' WHERE clientId = '".$clientId."';";

    //set results to variables
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        //in case query fails
        if (!$result2) { 
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
        }


    }
```

Form code:

```
echo
    '<form id = "needEmptyBoxesForm">
        <table class = "needEmptyBoxes1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="buttonText">
                        Our free signature boxes are 24"x18"x16", and double-walled to protect your items.  How many boxes would you like delivered?
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input      type="text"
                                    class="boxRequestBlank"
                                    id="boxes"
                                    name="boxes">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="buttonText">
                        Free tape will be delivered with the boxes.
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="buttonText">
                        Would you like to purchase bubble wrap for $5?
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input      type="radio"
                                    class="radioButton"
                                    name="bubbleWrap"
                                    value="1">
                        <span class="buttonText">
                            Yes
                        </span>
                    <input      type="radio"
                                    class="radioButton"
                                    name="bubbleWrap"
                                    value="0">
                        <span class="buttonText">
                            No
                        </span>
                </td>
                            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img        src="images/arrow.png"
                                    class="needEmptyBoxesFormForward1"
                                    id="needEmptyBoxesFormForward1">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class = "needEmptyBoxes2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="buttonText">
                        Please confirm  your address:
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>';

                        $sql = "SELECT  A.studentAddress1, A.studentAddress2
                        FROM clients A
                        WHERE '".$_SESSION["email"]."' = A.studentEmail";

                include "databaseConnection.php";

                //Close connection 
                mysql_close($connection); 

                    echo
                    '<input
                                    type="text"
                                    class="needEmptyBoxesTextbox"
                                    name="studentAddress1"
                                    value="'.$row["studentAddress1"].'">
                    <input
                                    type="text"
                                    class="needEmptyBoxesTextbox"
                                    name="studentAddress2"
                                    value="'.$row["studentAddress2"].'">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  <input        type="submit"
                    src="images/arrow.png"
                    class="needEmptyBoxesFormForward2"
                    id="needEmptyBoxesFormForward2">
</form>';
```

Comment: I have an 2 errors that say "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...." but I assume that is because I haven't done anything with the results yet.  Would that stop the second sql statement from processing?

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab and snoop your requests.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking after your query.  How to do this is outlined in the manual on `mysql_query()` or in this reference question.

Comment: put `$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)` after your `if` block.

Comment: @shiplu don't I already do this in my current code?

Comment: @pekka isn't this error checking? if (!$result2) { 
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());

Comment: no, because you're not checking right after your query and that leads to `mysql_fetch_array` breaking

Comment: okay, so now I have moved the error checking so that it is correct, as shiplu explained below...but the values are still not posting correctly, and I am getting blank values in my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... there's a lot I'd do differently here, and it might make a difference.

First, on your `.post()` command, I recommend using JSON:

```
$.post('needEmptyBoxesRequest.php', 
    {'boxes': boxes, 'bubbleWrap': bubbleWrap, 
    'studentAddress1': studentAddress1, 'studentAddress2': studentAddress2}, 
    function (response) { ...
```

Second, on your queries, I'd embed the strings:

```
 $sql =  "INSERT INTO supplies (`clientId`, `boxesRequested`, `bubbleWrapRequested`)
            VALUES ('$clientId', '$boxes', '$bubbleWrap');";
```

I don't think your form data is properly posting.

**UPDATE:**
After looking at your form code, I notice that you are refencing the inputs by ID in your jQuery,  but by name in your form code.  Please add `id` attributes to your inputs and see what happens.

Comment: you seem to be correct, after looking into this, bubbleWrap, studentAddress1, and studentAddress2 are not posting correctly.

Comment: I have added the JSON and embedded the strings, but still only "boxes" value seems to make it through, all others are wiped blank.

Comment: Then I think you need to post the form code so we can look at it.

Comment: good to go, I think, I trimmed out some of the middle stuff, so the formatting may look a little weird

Comment: indeed, there is a problem with your form code; also, you will want to use `htmlspecialchars()` on your `$row[]` data to prevent oddness with your web page.

Comment: sorry it got pasted wrong. Can you look again?  What is wrong with it?  I cycle through a couple tables using js within the same form.

Comment: please refer to my answer text; I updated it based on your update.

Comment: OH MAN!  What a DUMB error!  Thank you so much!  I will clean up the code now as per your other suggestions.  I feel like such an idiot, I think it's time for a break!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `&` in the query string you've constructed:

```
$.post('needEmptyBoxesRequest.php', 'boxes=' + boxes + '&bubbleWrap=' + bubbleWrap + '&studentAddress1=' + studentAddress1 + '&studentAddress2=' + studentAddress2,
//-----------------------------------------------------^^-----------------------------^^-------------------------------------^^
```

Comment: okay, so this was very helpful, I can't believe I forgot the &.  I have added them, but you helped me to realize that $bubbleWrap is also not posting

Answer (score 1):

Ajax Post is wrong. Use **JSON** to map parameters.

```
$.post(
    'needEmptyBoxesRequest.php', 
    {
        'boxes': boxes,
        'bubbleWrap': bubbleWrap,
        'studentAddress1':studentAddress1,
        'studentAddress2': studentAddress2
    },
    function (response) {
        alert('post');
        $("#needEmptyBoxesRequestResults").html(response);
        alert (response);
    }
);
```

Also **put your `if (!$result)` statements just after `mysql_query` call**. Like this

```
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
//in case query fails
if (!$result2) { 
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
}
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
```

Comment: Okay I have switched it to JSON as explained above, but it is still removing the values for everything except "boxes". I don't understand what you mean by "Also put your if (!$result) statements just after mysql_query call."  I think that I already have it like that.

Comment: `$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);` statement is in between `mysql_query` and `if`.

Comment: this did not seem to change anything.

Comment: I think the data is not getting posted correctly, any ideas for that?  I think the sql works, but the variables just don't contain anything.